# The appearance of a delay in the Object Stream after sending data

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, stream

I'm working on creating a network 2D shooter using sockets and JavaFX. The server starts on the user's computer, after which a second player can connect to it.
To transfer data, I use Object Output Stream and Object Input Stream and pass information through them in the stream. The problem is that while the players just move around - there are no delays, but with each shot the delay is getting stronger (the player has a shot, and the opponent has a delay of up to 3 seconds). Below is the code of the stream itself (identical for the client and server classes)

```
@Override
public void start() {
    try {
        outputStream= new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        inputStream= new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    AnimationTimer animationTimer = new AnimationTimer() { //JavaFX Animation Timer ~60 fps
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {

            movePlayerShip(); //we update the coordinates of the ship, in the same method the coordinates of this ship are constantly transmitted to the second player
            moveBackground();   
            movePlayerBullets(); // we move the bullets on the screen, it happens locally, data is not transferred to another player

            try {
                //we get an array of objects
                infoGet = (Object[]) inputStream.readObject();

                switch ((String)infoGet[0]){ //check on the first element what exactly came
                    case "playerMove": //if the opponent moves

                        shipOpponent.setLayoutX((double)infoGet[1]); //on the screen we move the ship in the same coordinates
                        shipOpponent.setLayoutY((double)infoGet[2]); //the ship is an ImageView

                        shipOpponentBox.setLayoutX((double)infoGet[3]); //hitbox also move
                        shipOpponentBox.setLayoutX((double)infoGet[4]);
                        infoGet = null; //clean to retrieve data
                        break;
                    case "shootPlayer": //if the opponent fired
                        //create a “bullet” on the screen with the same coordinates from which the opponent fired and set the same trajectory
                        MultiplayerBullet opBullet = new MultiplayerBullet((double) infoGet[3],(double) infoGet[4],0 );
                        opBullet.setTarget((double) infoGet[1],(double) infoGet[2] );

                        gamePane.getChildren().add(opBullet);
                        opponentBullets.add(opBullet); //add to arraylist with enemy bullets on the screen

                        shootSound.play(); //play the sound of a shot
                        shootSound.seek(Duration.ZERO); 

                        break;
                    default: //if unknown data arrived
                        System.out.println("got strange stuff");
                        break;
                    }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            moveOpponentBullets(); //updating all enemy bullets on the screen

        }
    };
    animationTimer.start();//animation start

}
```

This function is used to send a player’s position to an opponent:

```
    private void shootPlayer(MouseEvent event){

    MultiplayerBullet bullet = new MultiplayerBullet(shipPlayer.getLayoutX() + shipPlayer.getImage().getWidth() / 2, shipPlayer.getLayoutY() +  shipPlayer.getImage().getHeight()/2 , 1);
    bullet.setTarget(event.getSceneX(),event.getSceneY());

    infoSend[0] = "shootPlayer";
    infoSend[1] = event.getSceneX();
    infoSend[2] = event.getSceneY();
    infoSend[3] = bullet.getLayoutX();
    infoSend[4] = bullet.getLayoutY();

    try {
        outputStream.reset();
        outputStream.writeObject(infoSend);
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    playerBullets.add(bullet);  
    gamePane.getChildren().add(bullet); 
    shipPlayer.toFront();
}
```

This is a method to send a player’s position to an opponent:

```
 private void movePlayerShip(){

    if(isLeftKeyPressed){
        if(shipPlayer.getLayoutX() > 0 ){
            shipPlayer.setLayoutX(shipPlayer.getLayoutX() - 4 );
            shipPlayerBox.setX(shipPlayerBox.getX() - 4);
        }
    }


// Similarly, for the rest of the directions, I removed that there wouldn’t be much code.
 // Sending always occurs at the end of the method, even if the player did not move
    infoSend[0] = "playerMove";
    infoSend[1] = shipPlayer.getLayoutX();
    infoSend[2] = shipPlayer.getLayoutY();
    infoSend[3] = shipPlayerBox.getLayoutX();
    infoSend[4] = shipPlayerBox.getLayoutY();
    try {
        outputStream.reset();
        outputStream.writeObject(infoSend);
        outputStream.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I looked for information on this topic - I found only that you can set SetTcpNoDelay (true) and reset the stream for output. What can this problem be with the appearance of delays? In theory, another array of objects is simply sent. I tried to buffer streams when creating them

```
new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()))
```

but after this change, when the second player was connected, the game  stopped working.

Comment: This looks like you are trying hard to add every imaginable overhead to your application. The choice for a particular operation can be encoded into an integer constant, a `byte` would already support up to 256 operations. Even UHD screen positions still fit into a `short`. Instead, you are transferring a `String`, `double` values boxed to `Double`, an `Object[]` array containing these objects over a serialization that would be unnecessary for the primitive data, make roughly factor twenty in the amount of data.

Comment: But more important, you should read network data when they arrive, not when the UI timer tells you that it is a good time to update the UI according to the data you should have already processed.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your reply! I would like to clarify something:
1. Is it better to use a separate stream for sending and receiving data?
2. Is it better to send data in a two-dimensional byte array? When converting double to byte, an array is obtained, and at the same time I need to send several values of type double + add an identifier for the information to be sent

Comment: You are already using separate streams; they just belong to the same socket. This is fine. But don’t use `ObjectOutputStream`/`ObjectInputStream` without any need. You can work directly with `OutputStream`/`InputStream`. A flat byte array is enough, e.g. `static final byte PLAYER_MOVE = 1, SHOOT_PLAYER = 2;` • `byte[] data = new byte[1 + 8*4]; ByteBuffer.wrap(data).put(PLAYER_MOVE) .putDouble(shipPlayer.getLayoutX()) .putDouble(shipPlayer.getLayoutY()) .putDouble(shipPlayerBox.getLayoutX()) .putDouble(shipPlayerBox.getLayoutY()); socket.getOutputStream().write(data);`

Comment: As said, for screen coordinates, even `short` instead of `double` would be fine, needing only two bytes per value instead of eight. However, this is not the big problem. As said, more important is to fix the logic of doing network I/O in the UI timer. This is the reason for your delay, you are reading *one packet* per timer tick, missing one when the other side sent two. But trying to read more than the other side has sent would be even worse, then, your UI would get blocked. The network data should be processed in a different thread, then you can always read as much as is available.